# Unable to connect to attendance device using TAD library how do i solve this problem

Tags: php, biometrics, zkteco

I am using TAD class php for connection to ZKteco attendance device. I tried a number of solutions and code but failed to connect with the biometric device.

I studied the tad library and applied the code I am sharing the connection file I have enabled extensions socket and also soap php version is 7.2 the device IP is 100% correct if anyone point out actually what's the problem why it's not connecting. I also used ZKLib device is connecting on that but not getting connected using tad

```
<?php 
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'lib/TADFactory.php';
require 'lib/TAD.php';
require 'lib/TADResponse.php';
require 'lib/Providers/TADSoap.php';
require 'lib/Providers/TADZKLib.php';
require 'lib/Exceptions/ConnectionError.php';
require 'lib/Exceptions/FilterArgumentError.php';
require 'lib/Exceptions/UnrecognizedArgument.php';
require 'lib/Exceptions/UnrecognizedCommand.php';

use TADPHP\TADFactory;
use TADPHP\TAD;

echo "<h2>Tad Config Page</h2>";
// $tad_factory = new TADFactory(['ip'=>'192.168.100.13']);
// $b1 =$tad_factory->get_instance();
// var_dump($b1);


$tad = (new TADFactory(['ip' =>'192.168.100.13']))->get_instance();


if ($tad->is_alive()) {

    echo "Connected Successfully <br>";

    echo $dt = $tad->get_date();


}else 
{

    echo "Connection Failed";

}

?>
```

Comment: Developers please help me to solve this problem if any body knows any other API for bio-metric device connectivity. please share the link.